# DataGridView doesn't show anything when called from another class but works fine using form button

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

DataGridView doesn't show anything when called from another class but works fine using form button after form has completely loaded.

This works fine:

```
    Private Sub GetValuesButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetValuesButton.Click
        Try
            DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add("test", "test2")
                DataGridView1.Show()
                DataGridView1.Refresh()
                Application.DoEvents()

        Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
            MessageBox.Show("HRESULT = 0x" + ex.ErrorCode.ToString("X") + " " + ex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

This doesn't show anything on DataGridView:

```
    Public Sub Update_values(Filepath As String)
        Try
            Dim form As New AttSyncForm
            form.Show()
            form.TopMost = True
            form.Activate()
            DataGridView1.Rows.Clear()
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add("test", "test2")
                DataGridView1.Show()
                DataGridView1.Refresh()
                Application.DoEvents()

        Catch ex As System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
            MessageBox.Show("HRESULT = 0x" + ex.ErrorCode.ToString("X") + " " + ex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

I think this is somehow related to form loading, any ideas?

Comment: What form is DataGridView1 residing on? I guess the second set of code is running in a different class and DataGridView1 is on AttSyncForm. Your need to refer to it as form.DataGridView1 because it doesn't exist in your other class.

Comment: Neither code snippets should require a a Try block. I don't see any interaction with COM.

Comment: @Mary both of these methods are in same class with the datagridview, I'm just calling the sub from another class, nothing else. It even starts adding values for datagridview but wont show them. Even if I call that button click example on load event it will not populate gridview.

Comment: In Update_values you are creating a form and putting it on top. What form is this?

Comment: That is the form containing datagridview in same class.

Answer (score 0):

The code in Form1. The DataGridView1.Visible property is set to True in the designer.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("col1", "Test Name")
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add("col2", "Test Number")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Update_values()
End Sub

Public Sub Update_values()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add("test", "test2")
End Sub
```

The code in Form2.

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Form1.Update_values()
    End Sub

End Class
```

The code produces exactly the same results regardless if you click Button1 on Form1 or you click Button1 on Form2. I removed the .Clear so you can see the rows being added.